# Images disappear when resizing window in Kivy

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I've been following a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U14P8gtjQmU&index=5&list=PL4Yp6gRH-R1Birdm-Gs-SdBFWLUC1q3Fa) in Kivy and encounter a problem. When I'm changing the size of my window the images doesn't display. My code is:

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.app import App

class Sprite(Image):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size = self.texture_size

class Game(Widget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.background = Sprite(source="Sprites/CartoonForest.png")
        self.size = self.background.size
        self.add_widget(self.background)

class GameApp(App):
    def build(self):
        game = Game()
        Window.size = game.size
        return game

if __name__ == '__main__':
    GameApp().run()
```

I played around a bit, imported different images of different extensions and sizes, changed in the code and such, but only when I left out the line `Window.size = game.size` in the *build* method in *GameApp* it displayed the image. When I resized the window by dragging the corner of the image disappeared as well.

What is the reason for this and how could I fix the screen size to match the image size?

I'm using:

- Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.5
- PyCharm Community Edition 2016.1.4
- Python 3.5.2
- Kivy v1.9.1

Comment: I don't have problem with it on `master` branch. Try installing from source. Also, do your `super()` even work this way? O_ô

Comment: @KeyWeeUsr Are you also using OS X? Because I do believe it's a problem with OS X but I'm not sure and am still looking for an answer. `super()` is legit in Python 3.x so there's no problem in that area (I've used it in many other program as well).

Comment: I don't, but trying with master branch is quite a good idea. If it was a bug, it might be fixed for Mac too. Sorry for the `super()`, I still use py2.

Comment: This - https://github.com/kivy/kivy which is the official repository for kivy. Current master branch is at version 1.9.2 and you wrote that you use 1.9.1. How to install it is mentioned [here](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-osx.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bug of the current version I was using. Downloading the newer versions from [github](http://github.com/kivy/kivy) fixed the problem!